# Environment chaining in R

Tags: r, tdd, do.call, proto

In my R development I need to wrap function primitives in `proto` objects so that a number of arguments can be automatically passed to the functions when the `$perform()` method of the object is invoked. The function invocation internally happens via `do.call()`. All is well, except when the function attempts to access variables from the closure within which it is defined. In that case, the function cannot resolve the names.

Here is the smallest example I have found that reproduces the behavior:

```
library(proto)

make_command <- function(operation) {
  proto(
    func = operation,
    perform = function(., ...) {
      func <- with(., func) # unbinds proto method
      do.call(func, list(), envir=environment(operation))
    }  
    )
}

test_case <- function() {
  result <- 100  
  make_command(function() result)$perform()
}

# Will generate error:
# Error in function ()  : object 'result' not found
test_case()
```

I have a reproducible `testthat` test that also outputs a lot of diagnostic output. The diagnostic output has me stumped. By looking up the parent environment chain, my diagnostic code, which lives inside the function, finds and prints the very same variable the function fails to find. [See this gist.](https://gist.github.com/2957567).

How can the environment for `do.call` be set up correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was the final answer after an offline discussion with the poster:

```
make_command <- function(operation) {
 proto(perform = function(.) operation())
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your several follow-ups on this question. Could you help me understand why this works?  Does it go like this: **(1)** the `.` in the call to `proto()` refers to the evaluation frame/environment of the call to `make_command()`, which thus becomes the parent (i.e. `.super`) of the new proto object; so that **(2)** when `operation` is not found in the proto object, it is searched for and found in its `.super`; and then **(3)** `operation` itself has as environment the evaluation frame/environment of the call to `test_case()` (where `result` also lives)?

Comment: A proto object is an environment.  The proto object here has one component, `perform`, which is a function/method. `perform`'s environment is set to the proto object when it is inserted so when `perform` runs it first looks for `operation` in the proto object and when its not found there it looks in the proto object's parent.  The proto object's parent was not specified so it defaults to the environment in which the `proto` object was defined - which is the environment within the execution frame of `make_command` and there it finds `operation` as the argument.  See new FAQ  on proto home page.

Comment: Thanks for the additional questions/comment and thanks for the new FAQ.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue here is clearer and easier to explore if you:

- Replace the anonymous function within `make_command()` with a named one.
- Make that function open a `browser()` (instead of trying to get `result`). That way you can look around to see where you are and what's going on.

Try this, which should clarify the cause of your problem:

```
test_case <- function() {
  result <- 100  
  myFun <- function() browser()
  make_command(myFun)$perform()
}
test_case()
## Then from within the browser:
#
parent.env(environment())
# <environment: 0x0d8de854>
# attr(,"class")
# [1] "proto"       "environment"
get("result", parent.env(environment()))
# Error in get("result", parent.env(environment())) : 
#   object 'result' not found
#
parent.frame()
# <environment: 0x0d8ddfc0>
get("result", parent.frame())  ## (This works, so points towards a solution.)
# [1] 100
```

Here's the problem. Although you think you're evaluating `myFun()`, whose environment is the evaluation frame of `test_case()`, your call to `do.call(func, ...)` is really evaluating `func()`, whose environment is the `proto` environment within which it was defined. After looking for and not finding `result` in its own frame, the call to `func()` follows the rules of lexical scoping, and next looks in the `proto` environment. Neither it nor *its* parent environment contains an object named `result`, resulting in the error message you received.

If this doesn't immediately make sense, you can keep poking around within the browser. Here are a few further calls you might find helpful:

```
environment(get("myFun", parent.frame()))
ls(environment(get("myFun", parent.frame())))
environment(get("func", parent.env(environment())))
ls(environment(get("func", parent.env(environment()))))
```

Comment: Thanks, these are helpful debugging tips. What reading would you recommend for really understanding the scope chains in R?

Comment: One small point of clarification about your answer: the environment of func is the proto object's but not because this is where it is defined. Proto wraps functions in a class to turn them into instantiated methods. with(., func) unwraps them and _should_ have worked, except that proto's implementation actually resets the function's environment so that its code can access the internals of the proto object. It's that resetting happening behind the scenes that is the cause of the behavior (and the confusion).

Comment: @Sim -- Thanks for the clarification.  Section 13.3 of John Chambers' "Software for Data Analysis" gives a clear explanation of scoping in R. The one confusing thing he does it to consistently call enclosing environments "parent environments". I think that's unfortunate since it muddies the important distinction between the call stack (a chain of parent frames), and the chain of enclosing environments along which the evaluator searches to resolve the values of symbols not present in the local environment.

Comment: @Sim -- On a separate note, does replacing `make_command(function() result)$perform()` with
 `make_command(function() get("result", parent.frame()))$perform()`
(or its equivalent) solve your immediate problem for you?

Comment: Just a clarification of something said above.  When a function/method `f` is inserted into a proto object `p` using `p <- proto(... f = function(...) ...)`  the environment of the copy of  `f` inserted into `p` is changed to point to `p` but its class remains that of `"function"` and in all other respects `f` remains unchanged.  Instantiating `f` by writing `p$f` returns an object of class `c("instantiatedProtoMethod", "function")` .  Thus `with(p, f)` does not really unwrap `f` but simply returns `f` exactly as it exists in `p`.